# What is the hybridization of copper in blue vitriol?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hybridization

My book says that the structure of blue vitriol is the following:

[image: Blue Vitriol Structure]

From the structure, I figured that since there are 4 water molecules coordinated to the cuprate ion, the hybridization should be $sp^3$. But when I googled, I saw that people were saying its hybridization is $sp^3d^2$. Why would that be true?

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what mistake I made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The picture you provided shows half the story.

In the diagram above you can see that copper has a charge of +2 i.e. **Cu$^{2+}$** which leads to a **3d$^9$** configuration. Since H$_2$O will here act as a weak field ligand, no pairing of electrons will be done in d-orbitals which will lead to **sp$^3$d$^2$** hybridization.

[image]

Comment: Not a believer in hybridization of transition metals, but the structure is worth a +1.

Comment: I think sulphate ion doesn't form any coordinate covalent bond with cupper. But there exists an ionic bond between [Cu(H20)4]+2 and (SO4)-2. Because coordination number of Cu is 4 not 6.

Comment: @OscarLanzi How can we explain the average number of water molecules being 5 in blue vitriol? 2 H-bonded water molecules are bonded to 4 sulphate ions but on average 1 sulpahe ion is considered bonded with Cu(II) ion.